# How to customise the Laravel validation message property?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am using laravel, and would like to customise the message property that is returned if there are validation errors.

```
{
    "message": "The title field is required. (and 1 more error)",
    "errors": {
        "title": [
            "The title field is required."
        ],
        "slug": [
            "The slug field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

Please note, I am not talking about customising the individual error messages, I am referring to customising the message property that is returned that lists the first error and how many other errors there are.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75401572/edit) show the code for your validation? I have never seen that "(and 1 more error)" string 

Comment: It's probably part of Laravel's errorBag/messageBag, but I haven't found it yet -- It take that back, it's in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/41230#discussioncomment-3766482 Might help you

Comment: ^ Also explains why I haven't seen that, since I haven't had a chance to work on Laravel 9.x yet; good find @aynber 

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, I think @aynber you are right the logic is in the summarize method of: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php

Comment: Out of interest, without touching the vendor code, is there a way to override this method for my form validations?, if not I think I will just ignore the returned summarised 'message' property and just use the errors for my UI.

Comment: The link I provided showed an example of someone overriding the message part of the ValidationException. You can try that and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

All of the error messages that Laravel uses come from the **lang/en/validation.php** file. Of course if no other languages used. This file is a key-value pair and based on validation rule that fails it identifies the key and gets the message. If you want to customize the message you just need to change the value of that specific key and when validation error happens the same message will be shown  all over your views. If you wish you could create new rules and add custom messages for those rules as well. The way how exactly Laravel does the validation is a bit longer to describe but at the end there is an **Illuminate\Support\MessageBag.php** object available on your views that you use to access all the errors. That object reference is $errors. If you want to know more what you can do with this object check all the methods it offers: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/MessageBag.html. Often for an input field there are more than one rule that should be met. Of course the following rules aren't good enough for a phone number but they do just fine for what I want to show:

```
$request->validate([
   'numeric', 
   'min:10'
]);
```

With input like: "abc" this will fail in both cases, not a number and only three chars, at least 10. In this case MessageBag for the number as a key will have two different errors. And when you want to display you may choose which one you like. But most of the times it doesn't matter so you would choose the first one. That's why `$errors->first('number');`.

There are different ways of getting these errors but I'm not aware if you could modify the $errors properties. You could merge other errors but changing the value of an existing one not sure if you can do so. However if you really need to do this, consider doing something like this:

```
@if($errors->has('number'))    
   @foreach($errors->get('number') as $numberErrors)
      @if($numberErrors === "**Exact error message**."))
         <span>Custom error.</span>
      @else
         <span>{{$numberError}}</span>
      @endif    
   @endforeach 
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks PMekuli for your answer, I think the logic that i'm after is stored in the summarize method of vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.php